# trouble with margins in amsbook modification

Tags: margins, documentclass-writing, amsbook

I'm using the document class `iuthesis`, which is based on `amsbook`.  I've modified the distributed version (1.2.0.23: [source dtx available here](http://ryan.scherle.org/iuthesis/iuthesis.dtx), [stripped cls file here](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/iuthesis.cls), my modified version included below) a certain amount, and recently noticed an issue with page margins.

Here's a MWE that uses the modified class and demonstrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,abstractsigs,final]{iuthesis}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\pagestyle{jnwplain}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% Metadata
\author{Hope I. Passe}
\title{A dissertation that examines\\lots of interesting things}
\abstracttitle{A dissertation that examines lots of interesting things}

\advisor{Tad Vizer}
\secondreader{Yu R. Rong}
\thirdreader{Ar U. Shoer}
\fourthreader{Czech A. Ghen}
\fifthreader{Redd Marks}

\submitdate{\today}
\copyrightyear{2016}
\department{Miscellaneous Studies}

\begin{document}
    \fontdimen3\font=0.2em

    \begin{acknowledgements}
        \lipsum[7-11]
    \end{acknowledgements}

    \begin{abstract}
        Very abstract thoughts on the topic.  \lipsum[7-9]
    \end{abstract}

    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \signaturepage
    \copyrightpage
    \makeack
    \makeabstract
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter

    \chapter{Hargle}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

The following images show that the margins behave as desired in chapters, but behave differently in other sections, like the acknowledgements and abstract (shown), but also the table of contents, lists of figures and tables, and references.  In these sections, the vertical spacing above the title of the section is added to the top of each of the pages of the section as well.

[image: acknowledgements section has wrong spacing (second page)]
[image: abstract has wrong spacing (second page)]
[image: enter image description here (chapters have correct spacing)]

I can get the desired spacing behaviour (no top margin) by commenting out or removing the lines that create the section headings, e.g.

```
\@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}
```

Of course, I then lose the heading, as demonstrated by the following image:
[image: margins are good but now no heading]

I've played with it a bit, but have yet to find a way to create appropriate headings for these sections and not screw up the margins on following pages.  None of my adjustments the definition of `\@makeschapterhead` (version from my current `amsbook.cls`, from TeX Live, below) hasn't seemed to help either.

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
```

It's possible I've somehow screwed stuff up elsewhere in `iuthesis.cls`, so I'm providing the entire stripped version of that as well.

```
%%
%% This is file `iuthesis.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% iuthesis.dtx  (with options: `class')
%%   IUThesis Document Class (jonwashi)

%% iuthesis:  Document class for IU Thesis.
%% (jonwashi æʔ indiana.edu)
%% Copyright 2016
%% 
%% based on original by: N. Danner (ndanner@indiana.edu), 1999, v1.2.0.23

%% RCS Info:
%%      iuthesis.dtx,v 1.2.99 2016/07/16 jonwashi    


\def\fileversion{1.2.99}
\def\filedate{2016/07/16}


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01] \ProvidesClass{iuthesis}
\message{<< Class 'iuthesis', v\fileversion, \filedate (jonwashi) >>}

\newif\ifIUT@debugging \IUT@debuggingtrue \IUT@debuggingfalse
\def\IUT@dbgmsg#1{\ifIUT@debugging\message{#1}\fi}
\def\IUT@optionmsg#1{\message{  iuthesis option: #1}}

\def\IUTdraftmsg#1{}
\let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
\def\IUT@showdraftfoot{}
\DeclareOption{draft}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{draft}
  \def\IUTdraftmsg#1{\gdef\IUT@showdraftfoot{#1}}
  \let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
  \def\IUT@showdraftfoot{DRAFT: \today}
  \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{amsbook}
}

\DeclareOption{final}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{final}
  \def\IUTdraftmsg#1{}
  \let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
  \def\IUT@showdraftfoot{}
  \PassOptionsToClass{final}{amsbook}
}

\newcount\IUT@abstype
\newcount\IUT@nmlabstract\IUT@nmlabstract=0
\newcount\IUT@umiabstract\IUT@umiabstract=1
\newcount\IUT@ugsabstract\IUT@ugsabstract=2
\IUT@abstype=\IUT@nmlabstract
\DeclareOption{umiabstract}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{umiabstract}
  \IUT@abstype=\IUT@umiabstract
  \AtEndOfClass{\raggedbottom}
}
\newif\ifIUT@ugsabs
\IUT@ugsabsfalse
\DeclareOption{ugsabstract}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{ugsabstract}
  \IUT@abstype=\IUT@ugsabstract
  \AtEndOfClass{\raggedbottom}
}

\newif\ifIUT@abstractsigs
\DeclareOption{abstractsigs}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{abstractsigs}
  \IUT@abstractsigstrue
}
\DeclareOption{noabstractsigs}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{noabstractsigs}
  \IUT@abstractsigsfalse
}

\newif\ifIUT@noabstract
\IUT@noabstractfalse
\DeclareOption{noabstract}{
  \IUT@optionmsg{noabstract}
  \IUT@noabstracttrue
}

\DeclareOption{ms}{
  \AtEndOfClass{\degree{Master of Science}}
}
\DeclareOption{ma}{
  \AtEndOfClass{\degree{Master of Arts}}
}

\newif\ifIUT@three
\DeclareOption{three}{\IUT@threetrue}

\DeclareOption{single}{
  \AtEndOfClass{\def\IUT@blstretch{1}}
}

\DeclareOption{debug}{
  \IUT@debuggingtrue
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsbook}}
\ExecuteOptions{abstractsigs,draft}
\ProcessOptions

\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{amsbook}
\LoadClass{amsbook}[1995/01/27]

\topmargin 0pt
\oddsidemargin=.5in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\advance\headheight 2pt
\textwidth 6in
\textheight 8.9in
\advance\textheight by -\headheight
\advance\textheight by -\headsep
\advance\textheight by -\footskip
\marginparwidth 0.5in


\def\ps@chapter{
  \gdef\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddhead{
      \normalfont\scriptsize\hfil\rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}
    }
    \def\@oddfoot{
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}\hfill
    }
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \global\let\sectionmark\@gobble
  }
}

\def\ps@section{
  \gdef\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddhead{
      \normalfont\scriptsize\hfil\rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}
    }
    \def\@oddfoot{
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}\hfill
    }
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \gdef\sectionmark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\sectionrunhead{}}%
  }
}

\def\ps@chapsec{
  \gdef\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddhead{
      \normalfont\scriptsize\rlap{\leftmark{}{}}\hfill\llap{\rightmark{}{}}
    }
    \def\@oddfoot{
      \normalfont\scriptsize\rlap{\ttfamily\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}%
      \hfil\thepage\hfil
    }
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead\chaptername}%
    \gdef\sectionmark{
      \@secmark\markright\IUT@sectionrunhead{}}
  }
}

\def\IUT@sectionrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#3}%
    \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else%
    \@ifnotempty{#2}{\uppercase{#1 #2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{. }}%
    \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else\uppercasenonmath\@tempa\@tempa\fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{
    \normalfont\scriptsize
    \rlap{\ttfamily\IUT@showdraftfoot}\hfil\thepage\hfil
  }
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}

\def\ps@jnwplain{
  \gdef\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddfoot{
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}%
      \hfil\thepage\hfil
    }
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \global\let\sectionmark\@gobble
  }
}

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}\let\@author\relax
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}\uppercasenonmath\@title}\let\@title\relax

\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}\let\@submitdate\relax
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}\let\@department\relax
\def\departmentname#1{\gdef\@departmentname{#1}}\departmentname{Department}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\def\abstracttitle#1{\gdef\@abstracttitle{#1}\uppercasenonmath\@abstracttitle}\abstracttitle{\@title}

\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@principaladvisor{#1}}\let\@principaladvisor\relax
\def\secondreader#1{\gdef\@secondreader{#1}}\let\@secondreader\relax
\def\thirdreader#1{\gdef\@thirdreader{#1}}\let\@thirdreader\relax
\def\fourthreader#1{\gdef\@fourthreader{#1}}\let\@fourthreader\relax
\def\fifthreader#1{\gdef\@fifthreader{#1}}\let\@fifthreader\relax

\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}}
\let\@copyrightyear\relax

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {
  \centering
  \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \LARGE\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
      \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
      {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\def\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MIA@up}%
}

\def\MIA@up{%
  \def\@M##1\par{10000 \MakeUppercase{##1}\par}}

\newcommand \tocdotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand{\@dotsep}{4.5}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces \MakeUppercase{Chapter #2.}\quad}}\MakeUppercase{#3}\tocdotfill%
}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2.\quad}}#3\tocdotfill%
}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2.\quad}}#3\tocdotfill%
}
\renewcommand\tocappendix[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces \MakeUppercase{Appendix #2.}\quad}}\MakeUppercase{#3}\tocdotfill%
}

\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}



\newbox\dedicationbox
\newenvironment{dedication}{%
  \global\let\dedication\relax%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\dedicationbox\vbox\bgroup%
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\acknowledgebox
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \global\let\acknowledgements\relax%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\acknowledgebox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist%
    \item[]\ignorespaces
}{
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\prefacebox
\newenvironment{preface}{%
  \global\let\preface\relax%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\prefacebox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist%
    \item[]\ignorespaces
}{
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\referencesbox
\newenvironment{referencesbib}{%
  \global\let\referencesbib\relax%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\referencesbox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist%
    \item[]\ignorespaces
}{
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \global\let\abstract\relax%
  \bgroup%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalsize%
  \global\setbox\abstractbox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist\item[]\ignorespaces
}%
{
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
  \global\let\endabstract\relax
}

\def\IUT@defineabstract{
  \gdef\makeabstract{
    \typeout{Abstract}
    \bgroup
    \normalfont
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype>0%
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract pagestyle empty}%
      \pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \else%
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract pagestlye plain}%
    \fi%
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting title}%
      \begin{center}%
      \check@val\@author \\[.5\baselineskip]
      \check@val\@abstracttitle \\[.5\baselineskip]
      \end{center}%
      \vskip2\baselineskip
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Done}%
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract}%
    \unvbox\abstractbox
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype=\IUT@umiabstract%
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract (umi): advisor's name}%
      \vskip\baselineskip%
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfill\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype=\IUT@ugsabstract%
      \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract (ugs): signature lines}%
      \ifIUT@abstractsigs%
      \vbox{
\hbox to\textwidth{%
  \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}\hfill%
  \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}%
}%
\hbox to\textwidth{%
  \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}\hfill%
  \ifIUT@three\else\IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}\fi%
}%
\ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
  \hbox to\textwidth{%
    \hfill\IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}%
  }%
\fi%
      }
      \fi
    \else
      \ifIUT@abstractsigs%
    %\vskip-.1in
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \ifIUT@three\else%
      \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi%
    \ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
      \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi
    \fi

    \fi
    \newpage
    \egroup
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype>0
      \def\end@fterabstract{\end{document}}
    \else
      \def\end@fterabstract{}
    \fi
    \end@fterabstract
  }
}

\ifIUT@noabstract
  \ifnum\IUT@abstype>0\IUT@defineabstract\else\def\makeabstract{}\fi
\else
  \IUT@defineabstract
\fi

\ifnum\IUT@abstype>1
  \IUT@dbgmsg{Setting maketitle noop}
  \def\maketitle{}
\else
  \def\maketitle{
    \bgroup
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \hbox{}\vskip1in
    \bgroup
    \LARGE\bfseries
    \begin{center}
    \check@val\@title
    \end{center}
    \egroup
    \vfill
    \bgroup
    \Large
    \begin{center}
    \check@val\@author
    \end{center}
    \egroup
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
Submitted to the faculty of the University Graduate School \\
in partial fulfillment of the requirements \\
for the degree \\
\check@val\@degree \\
in the \check@val\@departmentname\ of \check@val\@department \\
Indiana University \\
    \check@val\@submitdate
    \end{center}
    \vskip.5in
    \egroup
    \newpage
  }
\fi

\ifnum\IUT@abstype>0
  \IUT@dbgmsg{Setting frontmatter commands noops}
  \def\signaturepage{}
  \def\copyrightpage{}
  \newcommand{\makededication}[1][]{}
  \def\makeack{}
\else
  \def\signaturepage{
    \typeout{Signature Page}
    \bgroup
    \noindent
 \begin{center}
    Accepted by the Graduate Faculty, Indiana University, in partial
    fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \check@val\@degree.
 \end{center}
 \vskip.5in
 Doctoral Committee
    \egroup
    \vskip.1in
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \ifIUT@three\else%
      \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi%
    \ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
      \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi
    \vfill
    \noindent\check@val\@submitdate
    \vfill
    \newpage
  }

  \def\copyrightpage{
    \typeout{Copyright Page}
    \hbox{}\vfill
    \begin{center}
    Copyright © \check@val\@copyrightyear \\
    \check@val\@author %\\
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
  }

  \newcommand{\makededication}[1][1in]{
    \ifvoid\dedicationbox\else
    \typeout{Dedication}
    \hbox{}\vskip#1\unvbox\dedicationbox\vfill%
    \newpage
    \fi
  }

  \def\makereferencesheading{
    \ifvoid\referencesbox\else
    \typeout{References}
    \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}
    \unvbox\referencesbox
    \newpage
    \fi
  }
\def\ReferenceBib{
\typeout{References}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{References}}
\@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}
}


  \def\makepreface{
    \ifvoid\prefacebox\else
    \typeout{Preface}
    \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}
    \unvbox\prefacebox
    \newpage
    \fi
  }


  \def\makeack{
    \ifvoid\acknowledgebox\else
    \typeout{Acknowledgements}
%    \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}
    \unvbox\acknowledgebox
    \newpage
    \fi
  }

\fi

\newcommand{\IUT@sig}[2][3in]{
   \vbox{%
    \hrule width 0pt height 1in depth 0pt%
    \hrule width #1 height .4pt depth 0pt%
    \vskip2mm%
    \hbox to #1{\hfill #2}%
   }
}
\newcommand{\IUT@shortsig}[2][3in]{
   \vbox{%
    \hrule width 0pt height 0.8in depth 0pt%
    \hrule width #1 height .4pt depth 0pt%
    \vskip2mm%
    \hbox to #1{\hfill #2}%
   }
}

\def\tableofcontents{
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalfont
      \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\@starttoc{toc}%

  \egroup
}
\def\listoffigures{
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalfont
\chapter*{\listfigurename}
\@starttoc{lof}
  \egroup
}
\def\listoftables{
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{List of Tables}}
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalfont
      \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\listtablename}}
\@starttoc{lot}
  \egroup

}
\def\listofmaps{
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{List of Maps}}
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalfont
      \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\listmapname}}
\@starttoc{lom}
  \egroup
}
\def\ReferencesBib{
\cleardoublepage
\bgroup
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
\normalfont
\@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont REFERENCES \tocdotfill}
}
%%%%
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}


\def\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}\pagestyle{plain}}

\def\mainmatter{
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}
  \normalfont
}

\def\backmatter{
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
  \normalfont
}

\def\check@val#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax%
    \typeout{}%
    \typeout{!!!!!!!!}%
    \typeout{Warning: #1 not set!}%
    \typeout{!!!!!!!!}%
    \hbox{???}%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

\renewcommand{\seename}{see}

\def\IUT@blstretch{1.67}
\ifnum\@mainsize=10\def\IUT@blstretch{1.67}\fi
\ifnum\@mainsize=11\def\IUT@blstretch{1.62}\fi
\ifnum\@mainsize=12\def\IUT@blstretch{1.66}\fi
\IUT@dbgmsg{Baseline stretch: \IUT@blstretch}

\pagestyle{chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\normalsize



\endinput
%%
%% End of file `iuthesis.cls'.
```

Perhaps someone can suggest an approach I haven't tried to fix this, or spot something I've missed?

Comment: Don't change `\topskip`. Look at how it is done for non-starred chapters where you introduce vertical space, but don't change things like `\topskip`. A global change to `\topskip` is going to remain in force until something later explicitly overrides it. You should just be adding extra vertical space here, which will only affect here.

Comment: If you edit the class file it's really _much_ better if you change the filename and change the author copyright and banner information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, I plan to do that and throw it on github eventually.  First I'd like to find out if it creates documents that will be accepted by the school, and maybe clean it up a bit too (but that can be done after it's on github).  And this issue is the last major one left, I think.

Comment: @cfr, `\topskip` is used that way in the `amsbook.cls` class definition.  Is it safe to redefine `\makeschapterhead` in my class file, or is it better to create a separate similar function for use in these other sections?

Comment: @cfr, using `\vspace` instead of `\topskip` does fix the problem, but gets rid of the margin on the first page of each section too, even when set to something really high.  Do you have a suggestion to mimic to the current behaviour on the first page?

Comment: @JonathanW. yes but you've _already_ posted it to this site as a world readable changed file but with the original copyright information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, point taken, metadata updated to reflect that.

Comment: Adding `\ps@empty` after `\endgroup` in the definition of `\makeschapterhead` (or rather, in a revised and renamed version of it) seems to do what I want.  I found this trick used in [another style file](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/7291605.STY) that seems to've been trying to get around a similar issue.

Comment: Adding `\ps@empty` also got rid of the page numbers, duh...  So I'm still looking for another way to get the same sort of spacing without screwing subsequent pages (or page numbers).

Comment: Adding `\topskip=0pt` after `\endgroup` seems to do it...  Is it unsafe to do it this way?

Answer (score 4):

It took me some time to recreate the problem as the code posted did not reproduce it. Please post code that reproduces the problem to avoid confusion and unnecessary misunderstandings, complexities and plagues of locusts.

If you change `\topskip`, you change the base layout of the page. This is not how chapter headings should be defined. That is not to say people don't do it. But it ought not be done. It greatly complicates things for no good reason whatsoever.

Instead, copy the definition of `\@makechapterhead` to `\makeschapterhead` and modify it appropriately.

I've also tried to eliminate the enormous number of potentially spurious spaces, though doubtless many more remain.

```
%%
%% This is file `iuthesis-jw.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Based on IUThesis Document Class
%% iuthesis.cls by: N. Danner (ndanner@indiana.edu), 1999, v1.2.0.23
%% generated from iuthesis.dtx  (with options: `class')

%% Modified as iuthesis.dtx,v 1.2.99 2016/07/16 jonwashi
%% iuthesis:  Document class for IU Thesis.
%% (jonwashi æʔ indiana.edu)
%% Copyright 2016

%% Renamed iuthesis-jw.cls 2027-02-04 version 1.2.99jw


\def\fileversion{1.2.99jw}
\def\filedate{2017/02/04}


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01] \ProvidesClass{iuthesis-jw}
\message{<< Class 'iuthesis-jw', v\fileversion, \filedate (jonwashi) >>}

\newif\ifIUT@debugging \IUT@debuggingtrue \IUT@debuggingfalse
\def\IUT@dbgmsg#1{\ifIUT@debugging\message{#1}\fi}
\def\IUT@optionmsg#1{\message{  iuthesis-jw option: #1}}

\def\IUTdraftmsg#1{}
\let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
\def\IUT@showdraftfoot{}
\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{draft}%
  \def\IUTdraftmsg#1{\gdef\IUT@showdraftfoot{#1}}%
  \let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
  \def\IUT@showdraftfoot{DRAFT: \today}%
  \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{amsbook}%
}

\DeclareOption{final}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{final}%
  \def\IUTdraftmsg#1{}%
  \let\draftmsg\IUTdraftmsg
  \def\IUT@showdraftfoot{}%
  \PassOptionsToClass{final}{amsbook}%
}

\newcount\IUT@abstype
\newcount\IUT@nmlabstract\IUT@nmlabstract=0
\newcount\IUT@umiabstract\IUT@umiabstract=1
\newcount\IUT@ugsabstract\IUT@ugsabstract=2
\IUT@abstype=\IUT@nmlabstract
\DeclareOption{umiabstract}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{umiabstract}%
  \IUT@abstype=\IUT@umiabstract
  \AtEndOfClass{\raggedbottom}%
}
\newif\ifIUT@ugsabs
\IUT@ugsabsfalse
\DeclareOption{ugsabstract}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{ugsabstract}%
  \IUT@abstype=\IUT@ugsabstract
  \AtEndOfClass{\raggedbottom}%
}

\newif\ifIUT@abstractsigs
\DeclareOption{abstractsigs}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{abstractsigs}%
  \IUT@abstractsigstrue
}
\DeclareOption{noabstractsigs}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{noabstractsigs}%
  \IUT@abstractsigsfalse
}

\newif\ifIUT@noabstract
\IUT@noabstractfalse
\DeclareOption{noabstract}{%
  \IUT@optionmsg{noabstract}%
  \IUT@noabstracttrue
}

\DeclareOption{ms}{%
  \AtEndOfClass{\degree{Master of Science}}%
}
\DeclareOption{ma}{%
  \AtEndOfClass{\degree{Master of Arts}}%
}

\newif\ifIUT@three
\DeclareOption{three}{\IUT@threetrue}

\DeclareOption{single}{%
  \AtEndOfClass{\def\IUT@blstretch{1}}%
}

\DeclareOption{debug}{%
  \IUT@debuggingtrue
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsbook}}
\ExecuteOptions{abstractsigs,draft}
\ProcessOptions

\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{amsbook}
\LoadClass{amsbook}[1995/01/27]

\topmargin 0pt
\oddsidemargin=.5in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\advance\headheight 2pt
\textwidth 6in
\textheight 8.9in
\advance\textheight by -\headheight
\advance\textheight by -\headsep
\advance\textheight by -\footskip
\marginparwidth 0.5in


\def\ps@chapter{%
  \gdef\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddhead{%
      \normalfont\scriptsize\hfil\rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}%
    }%
    \def\@oddfoot{%
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}\hfill
    }%
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \global\let\sectionmark\@gobble
  }%
}

\def\ps@section{%
  \gdef\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddhead{%
      \normalfont\scriptsize\hfil\rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}
    }%
    \def\@oddfoot{%
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}\hfill
    }%
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \gdef\sectionmark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\sectionrunhead{}}%
  }%
}

\def\ps@chapsec{%
  \gdef\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddhead{%
      \normalfont\scriptsize\rlap{\leftmark{}{}}\hfill\llap{\rightmark{}{}}%
    }%
    \def\@oddfoot{%
      \normalfont\scriptsize\rlap{\ttfamily\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}%
      \hfil\thepage\hfil
    }%
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead\chaptername}%
    \gdef\sectionmark{%
      \@secmark\markright\IUT@sectionrunhead{}}%
  }%
}

\def\IUT@sectionrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#3}%
  \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else
  \@ifnotempty{#2}{\uppercase{#1 #2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{. }}%
  \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else\uppercasenonmath\@tempa\@tempa\fi
  \fi
}

\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{%
    \normalfont\scriptsize
    \rlap{\ttfamily\IUT@showdraftfoot}\hfil\thepage\hfil
  }%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}

\def\ps@jnwplain{%
  \gdef\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddfoot{%
      \normalfont\ttfamily\scriptsize\rlap{\IUT@showdraftfoot\hfill}%
      \hfil\thepage\hfil
    }%
    \global\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \global\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \global\let\partmark\@gobble
    \gdef\chaptermark{%
      \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
    \global\let\sectionmark\@gobble
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}\let\@author\relax
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}\uppercasenonmath\@title}\let\@title\relax

\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}\let\@submitdate\relax
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}\let\@department\relax
\def\departmentname#1{\gdef\@departmentname{#1}}\departmentname{Department}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\def\abstracttitle#1{\gdef\@abstracttitle{#1}\uppercasenonmath\@abstracttitle}\abstracttitle{\@title}

\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@principaladvisor{#1}}\let\@principaladvisor\relax
\def\secondreader#1{\gdef\@secondreader{#1}}\let\@secondreader\relax
\def\thirdreader#1{\gdef\@thirdreader{#1}}\let\@thirdreader\relax
\def\fourthreader#1{\gdef\@fourthreader{#1}}\let\@fourthreader\relax
\def\fifthreader#1{\gdef\@fifthreader{#1}}\let\@fifthreader\relax

\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}}
\let\@copyrightyear\relax

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {%
    \centering
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \LARGE\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }%
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {%
    \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }%
}

\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\def\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
  {\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MIA@up}%
}

\def\MIA@up{%
  \def\@M##1\par{10000 \MakeUppercase{##1}\par}}

\newcommand \tocdotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand{\@dotsep}{4.5}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\renewcommand\tocchapter[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces \MakeUppercase{Chapter #2.}\quad}}\MakeUppercase{#3}\tocdotfill
}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2.\quad}}#3\tocdotfill
}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2.\quad}}#3\tocdotfill
}
\renewcommand\tocappendix[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces \MakeUppercase{Appendix #2.}\quad}}\MakeUppercase{#3}\tocdotfill
}

\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}



\newbox\dedicationbox
\newenvironment{dedication}{%
  \global\let\dedication\relax
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\dedicationbox\vbox\bgroup
  \begin{center}
  }{%
  \end{center}
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\acknowledgebox
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \global\let\acknowledgements\relax
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\acknowledgebox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist
  \item[]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\prefacebox
\newenvironment{preface}{%
  \global\let\preface\relax
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\prefacebox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist
  \item[]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}


\newbox\referencesbox
\newenvironment{referencesbib}{%
  \global\let\referencesbib\relax
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\referencesbox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist
  \item[]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \global\let\abstract\relax
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalsize
  \global\setbox\abstractbox\vbox\bgroup
  \trivlist\item[]\ignorespaces
}%
{%
  \endtrivlist
  \egroup\egroup
  \global\let\endabstract\relax
}

\def\IUT@defineabstract{%
  \gdef\makeabstract{%
    \typeout{Abstract}%
    \bgroup
    \normalfont
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype>0%
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract pagestyle empty}%
    \pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \else
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract pagestlye plain}%
    \fi
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting title}%
    \begin{center}%
      \check@val\@author \\[.5\baselineskip]
      \check@val\@abstracttitle \\[.5\baselineskip]
    \end{center}%
    \vskip2\baselineskip
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Done}%
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract: Setting abstract}%
    \unvbox\abstractbox
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype=\IUT@umiabstract%
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract (umi): advisor's name}%
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    \hbox to\hsize{\hfill\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype=\IUT@ugsabstract%
    \IUT@dbgmsg{makeabstract (ugs): signature lines}%
    \ifIUT@abstractsigs%
    \vbox{%
      \hbox to\textwidth{%
        \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}\hfill%
        \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}%
      }%
      \hbox to\textwidth{%
        \IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}\hfill%
        \ifIUT@three\else\IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}\fi%
      }%
      \ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
      \hbox to\textwidth{%
        \hfill\IUT@sig[2.5in]{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}%
      }%
      \fi%
    }%
    \fi
    \else
    \ifIUT@abstractsigs%
    %\vskip-.1in
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \ifIUT@three\else%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi%
    \ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@shortsig{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}}%
    \fi
    \fi

    \fi
    \newpage
    \egroup
    \ifnum\IUT@abstype>0
    \def\end@fterabstract{\end{document}}%
  \else
  \def\end@fterabstract{}%
  \fi
  \end@fterabstract
}%
}

\ifIUT@noabstract
\ifnum\IUT@abstype>0\IUT@defineabstract\else\def\makeabstract{}\fi
\else
\IUT@defineabstract
\fi

\ifnum\IUT@abstype>1
\IUT@dbgmsg{Setting maketitle noop}
\def\maketitle{}
\else
\def\maketitle{%
  \bgroup
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \hbox{}\vskip1in
  \bgroup
  \LARGE\bfseries
  \begin{center}
    \check@val\@title
  \end{center}
  \egroup
  \vfill
  \bgroup
  \Large
  \begin{center}
    \check@val\@author
  \end{center}
  \egroup
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Submitted to the faculty of the University Graduate School \\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements \\
    for the degree \\
    \check@val\@degree \\
    in the \check@val\@departmentname\ of \check@val\@department \\
    Indiana University \\
    \check@val\@submitdate
  \end{center}
  \vskip.5in
  \egroup
  \newpage
}
\fi

\ifnum\IUT@abstype>0
\IUT@dbgmsg{Setting frontmatter commands noops}
\def\signaturepage{}
\def\copyrightpage{}
\newcommand{\makededication}[1][]{}
\def\makeack{}
\else
\def\signaturepage{%
  \typeout{Signature Page}%
  \bgroup
  \noindent
  \begin{center}
    Accepted by the Graduate Faculty, Indiana University, in partial
    fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \check@val\@degree.
  \end{center}
  \vskip.5in
  Doctoral Committee
  \egroup
  \vskip.1in
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@principaladvisor, Ph.D.}}%
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@secondreader, Ph.D.}}%
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@thirdreader, Ph.D.}}%
  \ifIUT@three\else%
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@fourthreader, Ph.D.}}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\@fifthreader\relax\else%
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill\IUT@sig{\check@val\@fifthreader, Ph.D.}}%
  \fi
  \vfill
  \noindent\check@val\@submitdate
  \vfill
  \newpage
}

\def\copyrightpage{%
  \typeout{Copyright Page}%
  \hbox{}\vfill
  \begin{center}
    Copyright © \check@val\@copyrightyear \\
    \check@val\@author %\\
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \newpage
}

\newcommand{\makededication}[1][1in]{%
  \ifvoid\dedicationbox\else
  \typeout{Dedication}%
  \hbox{}\vskip#1\unvbox\dedicationbox\vfill%
  \newpage
  \fi
}

\def\makereferencesheading{%
  \ifvoid\referencesbox\else
  \typeout{References}%
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}%
  \unvbox\referencesbox
  \newpage
  \fi
}
\def\ReferenceBib{%
  \typeout{References}%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{References}}%
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}%
}


\def\makepreface{%
  \ifvoid\prefacebox\else
  \typeout{Preface}%
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}%
  \unvbox\prefacebox
  \newpage
  \fi
}


\def\makeack{%
  \ifvoid\acknowledgebox\else
  \typeout{Acknowledgements}%
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}%
  \unvbox\acknowledgebox
  \newpage
  \fi
}

\fi

\newcommand{\IUT@sig}[2][3in]{%
  \vbox{%
    \hrule width 0pt height 1in depth 0pt%
    \hrule width #1 height .4pt depth 0pt%
    \vskip2mm%
    \hbox to #1{\hfill #2}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\IUT@shortsig}[2][3in]{%
  \vbox{%
    \hrule width 0pt height 0.8in depth 0pt%
    \hrule width #1 height .4pt depth 0pt%
    \vskip2mm%
    \hbox to #1{\hfill #2}%
  }%
}

\def\tableofcontents{%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%

  \egroup
}
\def\listoffigures{%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
  \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
  \egroup
}
\def\listoftables{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{List of Tables}}%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\listtablename}}%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
  \egroup

}
\def\listofmaps{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocchapter{}{}{List of Maps}}%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{\listmapname}}%
  \@starttoc{lom}%
  \egroup
}
\def\ReferencesBib{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
  \@makeschapterhead{\MakeUppercase{References}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont REFERENCES \tocdotfill}%
}
%%%%
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}


\def\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}\pagestyle{plain}}

\def\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \pagestyle{headings}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\IUT@blstretch}%
  \normalfont
}

\def\backmatter{%
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
  \normalfont
}

\def\check@val#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \typeout{}%
  \typeout{!!!!!!!!}%
  \typeout{Warning: #1 not set!}%
  \typeout{!!!!!!!!}%
  \hbox{???}%
  \else
  #1%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand{\seename}{see}

\def\IUT@blstretch{1.67}
\ifnum\@mainsize=10\def\IUT@blstretch{1.67}\fi
\ifnum\@mainsize=11\def\IUT@blstretch{1.62}\fi
\ifnum\@mainsize=12\def\IUT@blstretch{1.66}\fi
\IUT@dbgmsg{Baseline stretch: \IUT@blstretch}

\pagestyle{chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\normalsize



\endinput
%%
%% End of file `iuthesis-jw.cls'.
```

Changing the class in the MWE to `iuthesis-jw` then produces

[image: acknowledgements, less plague of locusts]